# Check of the target cell value is matched to cells range value

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to set a input checking in excel marco file.
When user to input the column of recorded by and press enter, how to make VBA to check the target cell value (Column F:F) is matched one of cells range values (Column AB3:AD6)?

```
For example: 

Column F8 Jimmy <-> Column AB3:AD6   [TRUE]

Column F9 Johnny <-> Column AB3:AD6   [FALSE]
```

[image]
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Right click sheet tab > View Code > paste the code
- `MsgBox` is just a demo, modify as needed

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const LIST_RNG = "AB3:AD6"
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            ' If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:B10")) Is Nothing Then
            If .Column = 6 And .Row > 7 And Len(.Value) > 0 Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Dim c As Range
                Set c = Me.Range(LIST_RNG).Find(.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
                If c Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox "Bad"
                    ' Clear user input, modify as needed
                    .Value = ""
                    .Select
                Else
                    MsgBox "Good" ' modify as needed
                End If
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.Find method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144128)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Worksheet.Change event (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.comP/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)